# "Leadership is our drive. What's your?"

Tags: grammaticality, pronouns, sentence-fragments, slogan

[Here](https://sites.google.com/site/ncellcareers/), you may find a call to arms of sorts by the Swedish most prominent telco. I was born Russian, and I live in Sweden, so English is just about my third language. And so the following line does not sound right in my head:

> Leadership is our drive. What's your?

Well, I want to say, *what's yours?* but that doesn't seem to go with implied *drive*. But for some reason it sounds really wrong to me. I think it's idiomatic in inspiro-speak to leave out the *drive*-part, so I'm not complaining about omitted subjects and fragmentation.

So is *this* wrong? And if it's not — why do I feel like ending the punchline with *what's your?* sounds much worse than ending it with *what's yours?* ..?

Comment: While gramatically incorrect it got 35 people to look at their site and think about their slogan just from here in the last hour.  Personally that slogan would bug the crap out of me.   I can not see doing business with them.

Comment: @Chad, I'm not of the "any publicity is good publicity" persuasion. It's just appalling that huge companies say *nothing* so poorly.

Comment: I think this may have been a temp page or a work in progress.  This does not seem to be their current slogan.

Comment: @Chad, It's *live* on [their recent facebook promo, under careers](https://www.facebook.com/teliamax25?sk=app_218451551522470)

Comment: That's the way they say it in Swedish, maybe? You should know.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're correct, it should be "What's yours?" not "What's your?".  *Your* is a possessive adjective, and needs to be accompanied by a noun — so "What's your drive?" would be correct. Without the noun, you should use the possessive pronoun, "yours".

| PRONOUN | POSSESSIVE ADJECTIVE | POSSESSIVE PRONOUN |
| --- | --- | --- |
| I | my | mine |
| you | your | yours |
| he | his | his |
| she | her | hers |
| it | its | its |
| we | our | ours |
| they | their | theirs |

(from [Easy English](https://web.archive.org/web/20111013123047/http://www.easyenglish.com/lesson.asp?whose.txt))

I would also take issue with the first sentence; it should be "Leadership is our driver". When used as a noun, *drive* isn't something you're driven *by*, it's something you drive *on*.

So the corrected slogan would read:

> Leadership is our driver. What's yours?

Comment: Thank you very much for clearing it up! Although they'd probably wouldn't go for the driver-bit. Also I ruined your 1337-rep, sorry. :) :)

Comment: I would take issue with the semantics of this slogan, as well as the grammar. Frankly, I think both *leadership* and *drive* are largely vacuous jargon-words in this context, and if they mean anything here they mean about the same thing anyway.

Answer (score 2):

"What's your?" is incorrect.  "Your" is a possessive adjective.

So, to say "What is your?" is like saying "What is her?" or "What is his?"  It doesn't make sense because there's no noun in the sentence.

"Yours", however, is a pronoun.  So, saying "What is yours?" makes sense because there's a noun in the sentence.

Comment: Strangely *What is her* sounds much worse than *What is his*, maybe I'm in too deep. :)

Comment: Hmm... I think you're right about "What is his?" since that could also be a pronoun.  Nice catch.

Answer (score 0):

'Yours' as previously answered. But 'drive' is fine and should not be changed to 'driver'. This makes the slogan less about the attainment of the goal and more about being a passenger in the process.

Pronoun 'yours' aside. This is marketing language so is allowed/expected to be creative and noticeable, even break rules (?), and is a register in itself. Otherwise, Apple should be 'Think[ing] differently'.

Sometimes a 'wrong' message is more powerful than any correct notion of grammar.

Comment: If only their slogan were *think differently* instead of *think different*.

Answer (score -3):

It's perfectly correct; the "what's yours" is supposed to make you think about their slogan and to challenge you to be as good as them.

"Leadership is our drive. What's yours?" means "We work hard for leadership. What do you work hard for?"

It's not really idiomatic so much as clichéd business speak.

Comment: Ye, wait a second, that's not what I was getting at. If you note there's no **s** on the end of that *your* in their original, and the missing **s** is confusing me. Are you saying there shouldn't be an **s**?

Comment: @Gleno - sorry I inlined the 's' automatically